# Change network printer name in Windows 10

Tags: windows, networking, printing, printer, network-printer

In our company we have a network printer which has an ethernet connection and a web based interface for configuration.

If I have installed drivers for this printer on two computers, A and B, and on the computer B I change the printer name via

> Control Panel -> Devices and Printers -> Printer Properties

does it break the connection from the printer to the computer A, or will it only change the name locally for the computer B?

Comment: As far as I know, the name is local to the computer where it is set up, just as disc share names are.